# Prompt with pre-populated minibuffer input

Tags: completion, prompt

I need to prompt user for input, but I also would like to prepend the user's minibuffer input with a string. e.g.:

- user runs my function
- after the prompt, the text `awesome` (hardcoded string) is automatically inserted in the minibuffer
- user can start typing and it simply appends what she types to `awesome`, which is already there
- user types `bananas`, presses `RET`, the value returned is `awesome bananas`

User should also be able to modify `awesome` part of the string. For example one may chose to send `bad bananas` instead.

Can someone help me to achieve that? I've tried with `completing-read`, but can't get it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you need is `(read-string "input: " "awesome")`.

Comment: I don't have a `read-input` function, I think you meant `read-string`.

Comment: It looks like read-input is obsolete, and read-string is preferred. I updated the answer. Thanks for noting it!

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks John!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how you can tell `completing-read` to insert some text in the minibuffer by default, so you can append some more text that you type, to have the returned value be the result of the append.

That is, I don't think you're asking about prepending `awesome` to the *prompt*, but rather appending it to the prompt. I think you're saying that you want it to be *part of the returned value* (by default, i.e., if the user doesn't erase it), not part of the prompt. (I've edited your question along those lines. If I guessed wrong then please reject the edit.)

```el
(completing-read "My prompt: " '("awesome blue" "awesome red" "some" "other")
                 nil nil "awesome " nil "a default, if you want it")
```

The initial input is the 5th arg. The 3rd arg is `nil`, so you can enter anything you like - it need not match any of the completion candidates.  `C-h f completing-read` tells you:

> **`completing-read`** is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> `(completing-read PROMPT COLLECTION &optional PREDICATE REQUIRE-MATCH
>                   INITIAL-INPUT HIST DEF INHERIT-INPUT-METHOD)`
>
> Read a string in the minibuffer, with completion.
>
> `PROMPT` is a string to prompt with; normally it ends in a colon and a space.
>
> `COLLECTION` can be a list of strings, an alist, an obarray or a hash table.
>   `COLLECTION` can also be a function to do the completion itself.
>
> `PREDICATE` limits completion to a subset of `COLLECTION`.
>
> See `try-completion`, `all-completions`, `test-completion`,
>   and `completion-boundaries`, for more details on completion,
>   `COLLECTION`, and `PREDICATE`.  See also Info node `(elisp)Basic Completion`
>   for the details about completion, and Info node `(elisp)Programmed
>   Completion` for expectations from `COLLECTION` when it’s a function.
>
> `REQUIRE-MATCH` can take the following values:
>
> - `t` means that the user is not allowed to exit unless the input is (or
>     completes to) an element of `COLLECTION` or is null.
> - `nil` means that the user can exit with any input.
> - `confirm` means that the user can exit with any input, but she needs
>     to confirm her choice if the input is not an element of `COLLECTION`.
> - `confirm-after-completion` means that the user can exit with any
>     input, but she needs to confirm her choice if she called
>     `minibuffer-complete` right before `minibuffer-complete-and-exit`
>     and the input is not an element of `COLLECTION`.
> - anything else behaves like t except that typing `RET` does not exit if it
>     does non-null completion.
>
> If the input is null, `completing-read` returns `DEF`, or the first
>   element of the list of default values, or an empty string if `DEF` is
>   `nil`, regardless of the value of `REQUIRE-MATCH`.
>
> If `INITIAL-INPUT` is non-`nil`, insert it in the minibuffer initially,
>     with point positioned at the end.  If it is `(STRING . POSITION)`, the
>     initial input is `STRING`, but point is placed at *zero-indexed*
>     position `POSITION` in `STRING`.  (*Note* that this is different from
>     `read-from-minibuffer` and related functions, which use one-indexing
>     for `POSITION`.)  This feature is deprecated--it is best to pass `nil`
>     for `INITIAL-INPUT` and supply the default value `DEF` instead.  The
>     user can yank the default value into the minibuffer easily using
>     `M-n`.
>
> `HIST`, if non-`nil`, specifies a history list and optionally the initial
>     position in the list.  It can be a symbol, which is the history list
>     variable to use, or it can be a cons cell `(HISTVAR . HISTPOS)`.  In
>     that case, `HISTVAR` is the history list variable to use, and `HISTPOS`
>     is the initial position (the position in the list used by the
>     minibuffer history commands).  For consistency, you should also
>     specify that element of the history as the value of `INITIAL-INPUT`.
>     (This is the only case in which you should use `INITIAL-INPUT` instead
>     of `DEF`.)  Positions are counted starting from 1 at the beginning of
>     the list.  The variable `history-length` controls the maximum length
>     of a history list.
>
> `DEF`, if non-`nil`, is the default value or the list of default values.
>
> If `INHERIT-INPUT-METHOD` is non-`nil`, the minibuffer inherits the
>     current input method and the setting of `enable-multibyte-characters`.
>
> Completion ignores case if the ambient value of
>     `completion-ignore-case` is non-`nil`.
>
> See also `completing-read-function`.

You'll notice that it tells you that parameter `INITIAL-INPUT` is deprecated. That's nonsense, IMHO.  That just reflects someone's preference for not using it, as a user-interface style.  If you want input inserted initially, that's what it's for.  Whoever deprecated it is really just telling you that *you shouldn't want* input inserted initially.  If you want it then do it.

Comment: I noticed that `INITIAL-INPUT` is labelled as "deprecated" in many other functions... i really like to use it so your comment eliminated my doubts.